# LAMP-equivalent term for Ruby on Rails solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, architecture, ruby-on-rails-4, lamp

LAMP is a term that defines an architecture based on Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP.

How would you call an architecture based on Linux, ??? (Webrick?Unicorn?), PostgreSQL and Ruby?
LWPR? LUPR?

This is a silly question, but I would like to know how Rubyists using Rails describe their solution, just as LAMP solution are described as LAMP. I would like a similar "official" term.

Comment: I would say it is just what you said, LWPR or LUPR.  The reason why it is not used is because people refer to it as RoR(Ruby on Rails).  Since RoR is a framework it doesn't really matter what the other things are.  Now, if you use PHP without a framework like Laravel then it become LAMP.  With the framework you just simply refer to it as Laravel since it becomes less important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to refer to it simply as Ruby on Liweunpo.

But in reality, there isn't an official designation.  Too many people use all sorts of variations; the toolset is much richer today than when "LAMP" was coined, so it's much easier to pick and choose technologies and people aren't really confined to one stack anymore.  Even "LAMP" applications are increasingly more likely to use things like Postgres, because at the end of the day there isn't a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

LAMP usually consists of four parts:

- OS: Linux
- Web server: Apache with mod_php
- DB: MySQL
- Back end programming language: PHP

For Rubyists, I see many people use combination as below:

- OS: Linux
- Web server: Nginx with Unicorn (Webrick for development environment)
- DB: PostgreSQL (sqlite for development env. but better have the same db as production)
- Back end programming language: Ruby (on Rails)

Can't say the combination above is the majority of what people choose. So many other options are possible for each component. But that is a good starting point if you are new. You can see many tutorials with that combination.

Answer (score 1):

I learned today about *MEAN*: MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, Node.js (respectively: database, framework, server-side framework, client-side framework and web server).

It serves as a good example to show that you can build stack names to sound nice and memorable without having to respect any convention.

Comment: They missed a golden opportunity to call it NAME instead. Then when people asked what it was called, "who's on first?" would have ensued.